# Multiply connected region

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

Consider the region bounded by the Nyquist plot:
[image]

Why is the region not simply connected? I have trouble understanding if the area bounded by the small elliptical-like shape belongs to the region bounded by the Nyquist plot, explanation needed.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to talk about the "region bounded by a curve" if that curve intersects itself!

Comment: I am not sure, but during lecture it was claimed that the number of rotations around a critical point (related to Nyquist's stabiltiy criterion) were equal to how many times the region were connected. Simply connected = 1, etc. As you've mentioned this made sense when the curve didn't intersect itself...